# Robocopy specific files from subdirectories to a single directory

Tags: windows, command-line, robocopy

I want to copy files within many sub-directories that match specific pattern to a new directory. I don't want to copy the folder structure as I want all of the copied files to be contained within a single directory.

I've tried this:

```
Robocopy C:\Source C:\Destination *nbr6.tif \S
```

But again, I don't want to maintain the subdirectory structure.
I only want to copy files that match nbr6.tif and place in a single directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Powershell, you can try the following command line :

```
gci -Path C:\Source -file -recurse *nbr6.tif | % { copy $_.FullName C:\Destination }
```